# building a generic initializer function in java

Tags: java, initialization, default-value

I'm trying to come up with a function that lets me pass in any object and a default value, and if the object cannot be casted to the type of the default value, it should return that default value. If the object is null, it should also return the default value.

It should be used like this:

```
Integer myVar = ConversionHelper.initialize( "123", 0 ) // should return Integer(123)
Integer myVar = ConversionHelper.initialize( "hello", 0 ) // should return Integer(0)
```

and so on

I tried with the following code:

```
public static <T> T initialize(Object o, T def) {
    T ret;

    try {
        ret = (T) o;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ret = def;
    }

    return ret==null ? def : ret;
}
```

but it fails with basic conversions, like casting an Integer to a String.

EDIT: took many of the suggestions from the answers, and now I'm looking for a way to do it without the series of if.. elseif... elseif and the try catch block that appears in my answer

Comment: well, I just declared o as a plain Object and it seems to work, gonna make a couple of tests anyway...

Comment: well, I discovered that I cannot cast an Integer to String... I guess I'll target String as a special case and use toString()...

Comment: You need to use Integer.decode(myString). If it cannot be converted into an int, it will throw a NumberFormatException.

Comment: "I'm looking for a way to do it without the series of if.. elseif..." -> You just can't in Java. Plus there is an ambiguity, because "33" can be interpreted as an Integer or a Long (or even a String itself). How to decide?

Comment: I guess that's the definitive answer, it's not possible... as for "33", you would decide depending on the type of the default parameter... initialize("33", 0L) would try to convert to a Long and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcards are only valid as type *parameters*, not as types. In this case, as you noticed, plain old `Object` is just as good.

Another valid signature would be:

```
public static <IN, OUT> OUT initialize(IN o, OUT default) { ... }
```

But this looks to be unnecessary in your case, since the generic types are unbounded.

As for your strategy of conversion using casting within a try/catch, I'm not sure about it. Someone else should weigh in on that part.

**EDIT:** as you've discovered, casting is very limited when it comes to all but the simplest conversions of data. You may need to implement mappings to the appropriate parsing method calls depending on the in and out types.

**EDIT2:** as an example of what you're facing, here is a data conversion method somebody wrote for a project I'm on:

```
public static <T> T mapValueString(String valueString, Class<T> targetType) {

  if (valueString == null) {
     return null;
  }
  else if(targetType.equals(String.class)) {
     return (T)valueString;
  }
  else if (targetType.equals(Date.class)) {
     return (T)MyDateTime.parseDate(valueString);
  }
  else if (targetType.equals(Timestamp.class)) {
     return (T)MyDateTime.parseTimestamp(valueString);
  }
  else if (targetType.equals(Boolean.class)) {
     String upperVal = valueString.toUpperCase();
     if (upperVal.startsWith("T")) {
        return (T)Boolean.TRUE;
     }
     else if (upperVal.startsWith("F")) {
        return (T)Boolean.FALSE;
     }
     else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse value string into Boolean object. String was " + valueString + ".");
     }
  }
  else if (targetType.equals(Integer.class)) {
     Integer i;
     try {
        i = Integer.parseInt(valueString);
     }
     catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse value string into Integer object. String was " + valueString + ".", nfe);
     }
     return (T)i;
  }
  else if (targetType.equals(Long.class)) {
    Long l;
    try {
       l = Long.parseLong(valueString);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse value string into Long object. String was " + valueString + ".", nfe);
    }
    return (T)l;
  }
  else if (targetType.equals(Double.class)) {
     Double d;
     try {
        d = Double.parseDouble(valueString);
     }
     catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse value string into Double object. String was " + valueString + ".", nfe);
     }
     return (T)d;
  }
  else {
     throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported java type " + targetType.getName() + ".");
  }
}
```

Note that this is only for mapping `String` to `T`, where you want to map `T1` to `T2`. Is there a better way? Maybe. Can SO help you find the right strategy? Of course, but the ball's in your court to ask the right questions.

**EDIT3:** [Apache Commons' beanutils.converters](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/converters/package-summary.html) might be of help. I haven't tried it out though, so I can't remark on it.

Comment: Yeap, as you stated in your edit, I'm discovering it... how would you implement those mappings? so far now I'm doing it with plain olds if.. elseif... elseif... elseif inside a try catch...

Comment: thanks a lot for your last edit... I'll have a look at apache commons

Comment: @opensas you got me interested, so I asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061637/generic-data-type-conversion-method

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep an eye con that question!

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for:

```
public static <T> T initialize(Object o, T def) {

    if ( o == null ) return def;

    if ( def == null ) throw new NullPointerException("Null def");

    if ( !def.getClass().isAssignableFrom(o.getClass()) ) {
        return def;
    } else {
        return (T) o;
    }

}
```

However, you cannot use it on primitive types as you mention in your question. You would need to box them into objects to use this method.

**EDIT**

If `null` is a valid option then:

```
public static <T> T initialize(Object o, T def) {

    if ( o == null ) return def;

    if ( def == null ) null;

    if ( !def.getClass().isAssignableFrom(o.getClass()) ) {
        return def;
    } else {
        return (T) o;
    }

}
```

If the attribute retrieving the returned value cannot hold `null`, your compiler will tell you so via an error. Else, this code will fly.

Comment: very nice solution indeed, nevertheless a null should be a valid default value... BTW I'm surprised I cannot cast an integer as a string, see my comment...

Answer (score 2):

```
public static <T> T initialize(Object o, T def) {
    T ret;

    try {
        ret = def.getClass().cast(o);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ret = def;
    }

    return ret==null ? def : ret;
}
```

Comment: you should catch a `ClassCastException` instead.

Comment: This works, but is a bit dangerous since it does not check for the nullity of def.

Comment: yeah, I've just modified slightly the OP's code, I guess it's better to use isAssignableFrom like JVerstry suggested to avoid exception overhead

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all the answers, but I faced the following problem

with a couple of basics test, I soon found that the casting capability of types is limited (hey, java newbie around here), and I'm mainly thinking using it for basic types (numbers, strings, dates, boolean, etc)

so I came up with the following

```
public static <T> T initialize(Object o, T def) {

    if (o==null) return def;

    try {
        if (def.getClass().isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
            return (T) o.toString();
        } else if (def.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Integer.class)) {
                return (T) Integer.valueOf(o.toString());
        } else if (def.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Long.class)) {
            return (T) Long.valueOf(o.toString());
        } else if (def.getClass().isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())) {
            return (T) o;
        } else {
            return def;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return def;
    }
}
```

and I'll guess I'll just have to add many elseifs on the way...

oh, and these are the test I'm passing so far...

```
    assertEquals("trivial case, should return the value passed",
            "hello",
            initialize("hello", "default salutation"));

    assertEquals("should return the default value",
            "default salutation",
            initialize(null, "default salutation"));

    assertEquals("should convert to the default value type",
            "123",
            initialize(123, "0"));

    assertEquals("should convert to the default value type",
            (Long) 10L, 
            initialize("10", 0L));

    assertEquals("should return default value if it can't convert to the default value type",
            (Long) 0L,
            initialize("hola", 0L));
```

any better alternative???

Comment: You should either update your question, or ask a new one - don't put something like this in an answer. As for your situation, it's complicated because you theoretically have n^2 mappings to support, where n is the number of supported types. For example, how do you convert a `Date` to an `Integer`? (hint: not by parsing the Date's toString). That said, I'm sure something like this has been asked before.

Comment: yes, I thought about updating my question instead of answering it, but many answers would loose sense... I guess my question should be if it's possible to create a generic converter function for basic types in java without the n^2 mapping you are talking about...

Comment: Well I updated the question, but wanted to leave the original because I was aiming at something rather simple an general like that... but it seems like it's not possible...

Comment: @Opensas You would need to implement a separate method to cover for the conversion cases you are interested in. Java is too open from this angle for deterministic and unique interpretation. You need to make your own decisions to close gaps + handle all special cases between incompatible types.