# Generic data type conversion method

Tags: java, generics

This question is in response to another question by [opensas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47633/opensas): [building a generic initializer function in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061176/building-a-generic-initializer-function-in-java)

From his question it became clear that he needs to convert from any data type `T1` to another type `T2`. When I say "data type" here, I mean types limited to those commonly used to represent raw data: `Integer`, `String`, `Date`, etc. For the purpose of this question we can consider primitives to be boxed.

I'm wondering if there is any API that supports conversion between types where both the input and output are generalized to a set of supported data types. I had a look at [Apache Commons' beanutils.converters package](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/converters/package-summary.html), but there's a separate converter class for each known input. I'm looking for any functionality that implements something like the following signature:

```
static <IN, OUT> OUT convert(IN value, Class<OUT> targetType);
```

or else

```
static <IN, OUT> OUT convert(IN value, OUT defaultValue);
```

It really wouldn't be too hard to implement this kind of mapping oneself, either using a bunch of `else if` blocks pointing to the various Commons Converters, or else a `Map<Class<?>, Converter>` for the same purpose. But I'm wondering if this kind of functionality is supported somewhere.

Also, if this winds up being a duplicate I apologize. I tried finding similar questions and was surprised when I found none matching this situation.

**EDIT:** so an example of this code in action would be:

```
Integer i = GenericConverter.convert("123", Integer.class);    //returns 123
Date d = GenericConverter.convert(1313381772316L, Date.class); //returns today's date
Boolean b = GenericConverter.convert(0, Boolean.class);        //returns false
Long l = GenericConverter.convert("asdf", Long.class);         //RuntimeException
```

**UPDATE:** The BalusC code I linked falls close to the mark, and Bohemian's answer is a nice lightweight solution (although it doesn't work for Boolean conversions). He's also right that Dates should be probably be handled separately if we want to generalize conversion of these other data types. I'm still hoping for additional answers though - especially if there is more of a hands-off API available somewhere.

Comment: Can you show this code in action? Can't say I can really understand what's your goal.

Comment: @Maurício - added some examples

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In [JDK 8](http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/) this can be easily implemented with the new `java.util.functions.Mapper` interface and a [lambda expression](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html).

```
Mapper<String,Integer> atoi = s -> Integer.valueOf(s);
Integer r = atoi.map("10");
```

Using method references it can be even simpler:

```
Mapper<String, Integer> atoi = Integer::new;
Integer r = atoi.map("10");
```

Or things like:

```
List<Long> dates = asList(1344754620310L,1344754854877L);
List<Date> asDates = dates.map(Date::new).into(new ArrayList<Date>());
```

Or cool conversions like:

```
List<Integer> myInts = "5,4,3,2,1,0,6,7,8,9"
  .splitAsStream(",")
  .map(Integer::new)
  .into(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

In the current implementation of the JDK8 API, a few default mappers have been defined (i.e. `LongMapper`, `IntMapper`, `DoubleMapper`) and there's a utility class called `Mappers` that defines some others like a string mapper, and identity mapper, a constant mapper, etc.

I am not sure if this is what you are after, but certainly it must be a nice way to implement it.

Cases like the one you suggest for:

```
static <IN, OUT> OUT convert(IN value, Class<OUT> targetType);
```

Can be implemented with the `Mappers` utility class:

```
Mapper<String, Integer> atoi = Mappers.instantiate(String.class, Integer.class);
Integer r = atoi.map("10");
```

And your signature:

```
static <IN, OUT> OUT convert(IN value, OUT default);
```

Could be implemented with something like:

```
Mapper<String, Integer> atoi = chain(substitute(null, "0"), Integer::new);
Integer r = atoi.map(null); //produces 0
```

As such, a code like this...

```
List<String> data = asList("0", null, "2", null, "4", null, "6");
List<Integer> myInts = data.map(chain(substitute(null, "0"), Integer::new)).into(new ArrayList<Integer>());
System.out.println(myInts);
```

Would yield: `[0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6]`

Comment: +1 Great answer - I think I'll accept Dominic's until JDK 8 general availability.

Comment: It's 2016 now and there is no `java.util.functions.Mapper` but there is `java.util.function.Function`

Answer (score 22):

I am not aware of any library, however the code is just one line.

Apart from Date, all boxed primitives have a String construtor, so this method does the trick:

```
public static <I, O> O convert(I input, Class<O> outputClass) throws Exception {
    return input == null ? null : outputClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(input.toString());
}
```

To cater for Dates, you *could* use `instanceof` within the method, but I would recommend a separate method, since converting dates is a format- and context-sensitive thing (eg String-->Date parses and uses which format?, Long-->Date sets the time).

I have deliberately left error/special handling to the reader as an exercise.

Comment: +1 that's cool, didn't realize all boxed primitives had `String` constructors. Some of the conversions aren't supported, such as `Boolean`=>`Integer`, but then again that's a corner case. And as you point out this doesn't account for Dates (or other potential user-defined "data types")

Comment: Also: "I have deliberately left error/special handling to the reader as an exercise." I know you just wanted to get it on one line :)

Comment: type `I` is unnecessary here; it could just be `Object`

Comment: @user102008 maybe so, but the question has that signature

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spring Framework (spring-core), you can use class

```
org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService
```

Default constructor adds many types converter and you can add your own by implementing Converter interface and call addConverter(Converter). There is also nice [unit test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/DefaultConversionServiceTests.java) showing some conversion combinations.

Answer (score 2):

I found something by BalusC that looks close to what I'm asking for: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/08/generic-object-converter.html

Unfortunately nothing involving Date conversion is supported, but as the comments indicate, more conversion methods are easily added. His class is essentially a nice little framework that uses reflection to gather up all conversion methods at runtime and put them in a `HashMap<String, Method>` where the key `String` is a unique id for that input-output combination.

Still looking for other suggestions! Particularly for an API that would be more hands off than this code I linked to.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Variance](https://github.com/youdevise/variance), which allows you to set up a type conversion context with various converters registered and then move values into and out of a Variant type with type conversion handled by the context.

```
Variant aVariant = Variant.of("1.2345");
double aDouble = aVariant.doubleValue();

int anInt = Variant.of("12").intValue();
String aString = Variant.of(12.0).toString();
Date aDate = Variant.of("2012-04-06").as(Date.class);
String anIsoFormattedDate = Variant.of(aDate).in(isoDateFormattingContext).toString()
```

Converters are just [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [Functions](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html) from one type to another, and you can register your own, overriding existing conversions where desired.

Comment: Sadly, This is not in Maven repository.