# Equivalent of the Groovy's DefaultGroovyMethods#asType in Java (in a third party jar)

Tags: java, groovy, casting, type-conversion

I receive a `Map<String, Object>` from a call to an API outside my code.
This map can contain various type of values (String, Numbers, Date, Custom Objects, ...).

Edit:
For some non rational reasons, the values are sometime stored as the proper type in the map, but sometime a String representation is used. (So an integer can be found either as a java Integer or as a String.)

In order to avoid code like this:

```
Long numericValue = null;
Object val = map.get(key);
if(val!=null)  {
 numericValue = Long.parseLong(val.toString();
}
```

I would like to use something similar to the Groovy's [DefaultGroovyMethods#asType](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#asType(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class)) which perform checking and introspection to convert your data into the target type.

Is there any well known and lightweight library (jakarta commons, Guava, ...) that offers this kind of powerful conversion ?

Comment: Can't you use that Groovy's method as a lib?

Comment: Why not. but it will be a huge dependency for a small feature... I have to migrate groovy code to a java project that doesn't have groovy and this is for a class that is written in Java.

Comment: I guess so. Even though it is split into modules, groovy's core is rather large with ~2MB.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061637/generic-data-type-conversion-method

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll try to re-use the answer with a single line. looks good for what I need.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is similar functionality because  **Groovy is dynamic language but Java is static**. So using `asType()` method or `as` operator makes sense in Groovy.

In Java every similar type conversion will need to use a lot of reflection.

Groovy uses some useful build in functions. In Java you should most likely use helper methods and your own custom transformation.

Comment: I know what is groovy and what is java... I know that the asType method use reflection to get the type... But that's not impossible to implement in Java and I ask if someone knows one such implementation.